# XPath and PHP DomDocument - How to select all childs with specific tag and attribute

Tags: php, xml, xpath, domdocument

I have the element $paragraph in my DOMDocument:

```
<p class=4textlist>
    String 1
    <p class=4textlist> String 1.1</p>
<p class=4textlist>String 1.2</p>
    String 2
</p>
```

At one moment, I selected the element and I would like to get all the p tags from this elements that have the class "4textlist".

For that, I have try:

```
$result = $xpath->query('descendent::p[@class="4textlist"]', $paragraph);
```

But this is not working. Any idea please ?

Comment: `//p[@class='4textlist']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a typo in your query, `descendent` vs. `descendant`. `descendant::p[@class="4textlist"]` works fine.

You might also consider `.//p[@class="4textlist"]`.

Comment: Thank you @Jens, when changing to $xpath->query('descendant::p[@class="4textlist"]', $paragraph); this returns me 0 results. When doint with your 2nd proposal, I am getting all the 6 p tags with this class, I need to query only in the selected element, not in the entire domdocument.

Comment: Thanks again, but in this case, I am getting an empty result with the 2nd proposal.

Comment: Then your current context does not contain the elements. What does the XPath expression `.` return? Or are XML namespaces involved?

Comment: Hm, when trying to get the node value of the current $paragraph, I am getting the the content I am waiting for. The XPath expression . returns me a node list with 1 element.

Comment: Have you looked at that node? Is a matching paragraph contained in it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//p[@class="4textList"]
```

Comment: Thank you Axel, but as explained to Jens, this will return me all the p tags with this class, not the ones from the selected paragraph.